# Embed a shared live windows application within a Power point slide?

Tags: powerpoint, screensharing

Looking for ideas and advice on how to integrate an active application within power point presentation.

Want we want to do is share a live application (like you can within a MS teams, Zoom, Google Meet, etc..) within a live presentation. The app would on a different screen where we can control it.

I've had ideas on embedding Zoom or something into the slide and sharing through that but it all seems like a hack and I'm trying to keep it all local have the delays associated with sending data over the internet and network.

Any thoughts?
Is there a better presentation tool that might allow for this?

Thanks for your ideas!

---

I've had ideas on embedding Zoom or something into the slide and sharing through that but it all seems like a hack and I'm trying to keep it all local have the delays associated with sending data over the internet and network.